# rspec How to test if my yield is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I need to test that my method is yielding correctly, the implementation is something like

```
def method(val)
   @attr = yield(val) 
end
```

I wrote my test like:

```
expect{ |b| x.method(&b) }.to yield_control.once
```

The problem is that I need the @attr assigned to be able to fully complete my test. And the block `b` generated by spec don't return nil, so `@attr` becomes nil and that makes impossible to conclude the spec.

I basically need that the block return the same value that it receives.

I tried creating a lambda and expecting it to receive `call` but it's not working, I guess because is a block.

```
l = ->(k,v) { v } # I set the return value
expect(l).to receive(:call).once
x.method(&l)
# call is not called
```

How I can check if `l` is executed if is converted to a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is create another lambda that is called from inside the original call and return the original value. like this:

```
x = ->(v) { v }
l = ->(k,v) { x.call(k, v) }
expect(x).to receive(:call)
```

Whoala